# Sitecore Forms custom Condition

Tags: sitecore-forms

With Sitecore 9.1 there is option to add condition and based on these condition a field or section or page can be display, hide etc.
But OOTB only has the condition to compare a fields value with a particular text like:
Contains,StartsWith,Endswith etc.

**How can i add custom condition**?
Example: Suppose i need to check if the field is empty or not then enable or disable a button.

Comment: https://blog.inspeerity.com/sitecore/sitecore-forms-create-new-conditions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have for Sitecore 9.3. You can simply leave the comparison text as empty like below:

[image]

and the condition logic then shows as:
[image]

Comment: This works for 9.1 as well. Thank you